# How to calculate time differences?

Tags: python, date, time

This is my code to find the time difference. You input hour and time of your preference. Remaining time is calculated by finding the difference between your input and current time but it is not working for me.

```
time_hour = input("Enter hour: ")
time_minutes = input("Enter minutes: ")
set_time = time_hour + ":" + time_minutes
print("Set Time: ", set_time)

now = datetime.now()    
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time: ", current_time)

dif = set_time - current_time
print(dif)
```

I am able to get the set time and current time, but not the difference.

This is the output of the program:

```
Enter hour: 10
Enter minutes: 30
Set Time:  10:30
Current Time:  11:14
```

Comment: You are trying to subtract 2 strings. You need to convert `set_time` and `current_time` to a `datetime` object and then you can find the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

You are actually subtracting string from datetime, so convert the first input time to datetime first

```
time_hour = input("Enter hour: ")
time_minutes = input("Enter minutes: ")
set_time = time_hour + ":" + time_minutes
the_time = datetime.strptime(set_time,'%H:%M')
now = datetime.now()    
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time: ", current_time)
dif = the_time - current_time
print(dif)
```

Comment: I tried your version but I am not getting the dif. I am getting something like this:
Enter hour: 10
Enter minutes: 30
Current Time:  11:52